# How to modify this C++ class to be as efficient as C code?

Tags: c++, c, optimization

Today I've wanted to check if it is possible to write C++ code that is as efficient as C code. Because I'm working on an embedded system, I want to make sure using C++ will not impact performance too much.
So I've written a C code for manipulating fake GPIOs registers, as well as its C++ counterpart.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#define PUSH_BUTTON_PORT 0
#define PUSH_BUTTON_PIN 4

volatile int port0_pin_dir= 0;
volatile int port0_pin_read = 0;

void inline gpio_init_input(unsigned int port, unsigned int pin)
{
    switch (port)
    {
        case 0:
            port0_pin_dir |= 1 << pin;
        break;
        case 1:
            //manage port 1 direction register...
        break;
    }
}

bool inline gpio_read(unsigned int port, unsigned int pin)
{
    switch (port)
    {
        case 0:
            return (port0_pin_read >> pin) & 1;
        case 1:
            //TODO: manage port 1 direction register...
            return 0;
    }
}

volatile bool is_pressed = 0;
int main()
{
    gpio_init_input(PUSH_BUTTON_PORT, PUSH_BUTTON_PIN);
    is_pressed = gpio_read(PUSH_BUTTON_PORT, PUSH_BUTTON_PIN);
    return 0;
}
```

equivalent C++ code:

```
volatile int port0_pin_dir = 0;
volatile int port0_pin_read = 0;

template<unsigned int PORT, unsigned int PIN>
class gpio
{
public:
    gpio()
    {
        static_assert(PORT < 2, "This chip has only 2 gpio ports");
        static_assert(PIN < 32, "This pins has 32 pins per port");
    }

    void init_input()
    {
        switch (PORT)
        {
            case 0:
                port0_pin_dir |= 1 << PIN;
            break;
            case 1:
                //TODO: manage port 1 direction register...
            break;
        }
    }

    bool read()
    {
        switch (PORT)
        {
            case 0:
                return (port0_pin_read >> PIN) & 1;
            case 1:
                //TODO: manage port 1 direction register...
                return 0;
        }
        
    }
};

volatile bool is_pressed = false;
int main()
{
    gpio<0,4> push_button;
    push_button.init_input();
    is_pressed = push_button.read();
    return 0;
}
```

If I enable -O3 optimization, both source codes result in exactly the same compiler output, which is great. You can check by yourself here:
https://godbolt.org/z/P7ov8E for C++, and here https://godbolt.org/z/Kav6qb for C.

Now assume I need to iterate through the gpios to initialize a bunch of them as inputs. In C it is quite easy, and I would add this to the main() function:

```
for (int i =0; i<10;i++)
{
    gpio_init_input(PUSH_BUTTON_PORT, i);
}
```

For the C++ version, I had to re-write the class because it was a templated class, and you can't easily iterate through multiples types of a class.

So here is the new C++ code:

```
volatile int port0_pin_dir = 0;
volatile int port0_pin_read = 0;

class gpio
{
    unsigned int port;
    unsigned int pin;
public:
    gpio(unsigned int port, unsigned int pin)
    {
        port = port;
        pin = pin;
    }

    void init_input()
    {
        switch (port)
        {
            case 0:
                port0_pin_dir |= 1 << pin;
            break;
            case 1:
                //TODO: manage port 1 direction register...
            break;
        }
    }

    bool read()
    {
        switch (port)
        {
            case 0:
                return (port0_pin_read >> pin) & 1;
            case 1:
                //TODO: manage port 1 direction register...
                return 0;
        }
        
    }
};

volatile bool is_pressed = false;
int main()
{
    gpio push_button(0,4);
    push_button.init_input();
    is_pressed = push_button.read();

    for (int i =0; i<10;i++)
    {
        gpio pin(0,i);
        pin.init_input();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see here https://godbolt.org/z/dzMnds for the C++ version and here https://godbolt.org/z/4czfKx for the C version, the C++ compiler output is about 25% bigger than the C counterpart.

So is their a way of using a C++ class in this case without compromising efficiency (over C)?

Comment: Unless your code is a bottleneck you probably don't need to care, and even if it is a bottle neck, the difference is probably too small to be noticed. To be sure you need to mesure.

Comment: Why you need some "IO-Handling" function and that bunch of switch cases? In my bare metal projects the ports have all known functionality and initialized more or less to a fixed value and the readout/write is always done by direct port register access, mostly on IRQ level. For me, unknown of your scenario, I can't see the use case of all that handlers...

Comment: In the C version, you are using the same instance of the code every time.  In the C++ version, you are creating a different instance inside the loop.

Comment: Why are you insisting on using a `class` in the C++ version?   The C version demonstrates that is unnecessary, and there is nothing gained by doing so.

Comment: @Peter Actually, this is a simplified version of a gpio class, which in reality offers a lot more features. Imo, it is easier to write bug free code in C++, because of the strong typing, and I also don't like having tons of #defines in my code. Of course this is a personal POV, I don't want to begin a C/C++ programmer war :) The point is, it is possible to produce exactly the same output using both of the programming languages.

Comment: I'm not sure what changed, though both C and C++ examples at compiler explorer show me the same assembly (with 1 difference: sar vs shr instruction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following change helps

```
class gpio
{
    const unsigned int port;
    const unsigned int pin;
public:
    gpio(unsigned int port, unsigned int pin) : port(port), pin(pin)
    {
    }
```

By declaring the member variables as `const` (and consequently using an initialisation list in the constructor) it helps the compiler optimise their use.

I'm no expert on reading assembly, but that seems to make the two programs compile to equivalent code.